# How to get id from ajax request and then send it to symfony function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, routes, twig

i make a create function i want to store id in a variable and then pass this id to edit function,i write some code for this but error exist,how i do this?
here is my code:

```
  var InvoiceId;
  $("form").submit(function(e) {                
         e.preventDefault();
         var url = $(this).attr('action');
         var data = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
         })
         .success(function( result )  {
                invoiceid=result.id;
                $("#edit").click(); 
            if(result.success) {
                $('#result').css({'color':'black','background-color':'#8F8','display':'Block','width':'200px'});
                $('#result').html('Invoices Record Inserted');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#result').hide();
                    },3000);
                    window.location.href = "{{ path('invoicepreview') }}";
            }
         });
         this.reset();
     });
     $("#edit").click(function(){
  = "{{ path('invoices_edit', {'id': invoiceid }) }}";
});
```

here is my create function:

```
 if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $response = new Response();
        $output = array('success' => true, 'title' => $entity->gettitle(), 'id' => $entity->getId(), 'notes' => $entity->getnotes(), 'accountid' => $entity->getaccountid(), 'clientid' => $entity->getClientID(), 'status' => $entity->getstatus(), 'totalamount' => $entity->getTotalAmount(), 'paidamount' => $entity->getPaidAmount(), 'balanceamount' => $entity->getBalanceAmount(), 'createdby' => $entity->getcreatedby(), 'updatedby' => $entity->getupdatedby(), 'createddatetime' => $entity->getcreateddatetime(), 'updateddatetime' => $entity->getupdateddatetime());
         $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
         $response->setContent(json_encode($output));

    }
```

here is my edit function:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoices')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Invoices entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new InvoicesType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoices:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

here is error:

```
Variable "invoiceid" does not exist in InvoicesInvoicesBundle:Invoices:new.html.twig at line 362
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be generating paths dynamically within JS, especially if you're doing loads of AJAX-y stuff, you almost certainly want to add the FOS's [JS Routing Bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle) to your project

After correct configuration your JS for the path would be something like

```
Routing.generate('invoices_edit', { id: invoiceid });
```

Instructions on how to configure paths and routes for use with JSBundle can be found [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown)

Comment: This is a correct and working solution. *"Not working"* isn't an error. Did you follow the installation steps correctly?